# How to convert string contains datetime in isoformat to date and time values?

Tags: python

I have the following string format (Python 3.6):

```
'2018-11-19T10:04:57.426872'
```

I get it as a parameter to my script.
I want to get the date as `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and time as `'HH:MM'`

I tried to convert it with:

```
from datetime import datetime
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_timestamp = sys.argv[1]
    start_date =  datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%Y-%m-%d')
    start_time =  datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%H:%M')
```

But this gives:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T10:04:57.426872
```

In the above example I want to see:

```
start_date = '2018-11-19'
start_time = '10:04'
```

Comment: The pattern you give as an argument to `strptime` must cover the whole string, otherwise it is unclear where those info is in the string. Als for extracting hours and minutes: if your pattern would work, would it extract `10:04` or `04:57`?

Comment: @ChristianKönig When I do: `print datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()`   I get: `2018-11-19T12:01:54.579000`   and when I do print `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`  I get `2018-11-19 12:01:54.579000`     so the `start_time` in this case should be `12:01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the date seems to be in ISO-Format, a simple

```
start = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(text)
```

will parse it correctly. From there you can get your date and time with

```
start_date = start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_time = start.strftime("%H:%M")
```

***Edit:***

For Python < 3.7, you can use this format:

```
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(text, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

For the "duplicate" datetime confusion: I used `import datetime`. If you use `from datetime import datetime`, you can get rid of the additional `datetime.`

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Comment: @Luis just remove one `datetime` so you read `start = datetime.fromisoformat(text)`

Comment: Ah, you're right - [*New in version 3.7*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). Will edit.

Comment: @toti08 already did that. The error is after I removed the redundant datetime.   I think this function is introduced in Python 3.7 I run Python 3.6

Comment: @toti08 I tried datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(start_timestamp) and also datetime.fromisoformat(start_timestamp)   It's the same error. This function isn't available for Python 3.6

Comment: @Luis I see, then you have no other option than the manual conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:We have one of the best package for parsing dates called dateutil.

```
from dateutil import parser
date1='2018-11-19T10:04:57.426872'
print 'Start_date:',parser.parse(date1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
print 'Start_time:',parser.parse(date1).strftime("%H:%M")

Result:Start_date:2018-11-19
       Start_time:10:04
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the entire string into one datetime object and then extract your required values from that.

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-11-19T10:04:57.426872', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
d = dt.date()
t = dt.time()
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print(t.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Which outputs:

```
2018-11-19
10:04
```